# Rabbitmq - How to check if given queue is in use or when last time it got any message

Tags: rabbitmq, monitoring

Imagine there are 200+ microservices on your server they routinely communicate with each other via rabbitmq. As life goes on, so microservices are decommissioned, some are brought to life, standard development cycle continues. After a while one of the queues stopped being used, microservices that was pushing messages to it, ceased to exist.

Is there a way to check when the given queue got a message last time? Or when last time the message was consumed from the queue? Basically eternally idle queues that outlived their purpose. At the moment I have access only to the standard rabbitmq admin panel and I would guess to have such information I would need to install some sort of 3rd party tool? Any recommendation on that?